# how to create simple derived type from XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, rex

how to can I create derived simpleType in your XSD file BASED ON xs:ID. The restriction should use a pattern with a value that starts with a "_", followed by two characters that are digits in the range 1 - 8.

element from xml

```
  <piece identifier="p" postion="_44"></piece>
```

XSD

```
     <xs:attribute name="postion">
                         <xs:simpleType>
                           <xs:restriction base="xs:ID">
                             <xs:pattern value="??">
                           </xs:restriction>
                         </xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the redexp is _[1-8][1-8]

```
 <xs:attribute name="postion">
                     <xs:simpleType>
                       <xs:restriction base="xs:ID">
                         <xs:pattern value="_[1-8][1-8]">
                       </xs:restriction>
                     </xs:simpleType>
```